# android open app with touch on notification

Tags: android

at the moment i set an notification in my android app like this:

```
private Notification getNotification(String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setTicker(content);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_appicon);
    builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500);
    return builder.getNotification();
}
```

Problem is, that i would like to press on the notification which should  open the app. but if i touch on the notification, nothing happens.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a contentIntent for your notification. Start your learning tour here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Actions or here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html#notificationmanager_configure

Answer (score 2):

You need to set [setContentIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) to your notification builder

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
PendingIntent yourPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
builder.setContentIntent(yourPendingIntent);
```

You can refer this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `PendingIntent` in `builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)` to start actvity.

```
private Notification getNotification(String content) {
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
builder.setContentText(content);
builder.setTicker(content);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_appicon);
builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500);
// This intent is fired when notification is clicked
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YouMainActvity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
 return builder.getNotification();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find a whole example here: http://android-er.blogspot.bg/2013/06/start-activity-once-notification-clicked.html or try something like this:

```
 private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;

 Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, DoSomething.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 
        0, 
        myIntent, 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

 Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
   .setContentTitle("Notification!")
   .setContentText("Do Something...")
   .setTicker("Notification!!!")
   .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
   .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
   .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
   .setAutoCancel(true)
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
   .build();

 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
```